# python 'constants' and changing them

Tags: python, constants, pep

Hi this is more of a style question. I have a small script that works with a socket, and I have constants (i know they are not real constants, but heyy, at least they are in capital) that declare some properties,

```
# Port address for the serial port to read the weight from
PADDR = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
# socket address uri, backlog, and buffer
SADDR = 'localhost:28000'
BACKLG = 0
BUFF = 1024
# for cross platform compatibility use epoch in unix time
EPOCH_START = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
```

I however might add functionality to change these by parsing arguments. So the question is, should I just change these directly when parsing arguments?

or should I be nice and use the above constants as defaults and change the options which I would then pass around to functions who need them? This seems a bit too much, but then again, I don't want to write code that will be frowned upon :)

Comment: Why not use an actual argument parser that supports default values properly?

Comment: I just started doing it actually. But want to keep the constants at the top too, to make things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `DEFAULT_PADDR` as a constant; but `paddr` as a variable with `DEFAULT_PADDR` as its default value. Do not change a "constant", even if it is just a matter of style - your code becomes cryptic.

I.e. for now, do this:

```
DEFAULT_PADDR = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
# ...
paddr = DEFAULT_PADDR
```

then you can change `paddr` when you add argument parsing.

Comment: kool. I was now thinking the same, but didn't occur that i could put `DEFAULT` before. I didn't want to have `PADDR` and `paddr` :)